# JQuery using each inside other function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, this, each

I am using an AJAX function, and with the result I am doing a `$('.class').each` to perform some logic.

The problem is that calling `$(this)` to retrieve to each object, refers to the AJAX function instead of the element found.

How can I refer to the element found in the `each` function?

```
$.ajax({url: "myurl", success: function(result){

                $(".my_class").each((index, dom) => {

                    console.log(($(this)));   //this is the ajax funct, not the object i want

                });

         });
```

Comment: Drop the arrow function and use `function(index,dom) {}`

Comment: @LGSon wow thanks, i thought that the arrow function was just a shorthand, why are they behaving different??

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch

Comment: Read up on the dupe links and you get some good explanations

Comment: thanks, it is clear now :)